# How to change FusedLocationApi update interval after requestLocationUpdates has been called

Tags: android, google-play-services, fusedlocationproviderapi

I am using LocationServices.FusedLocationApi to get location updates at a given interval, which is set on the LocationRequest object that is passed to requestLocationUpdates:

```
mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
mLocationRequest.setInterval(30000);
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
```

I need to change the value of the interval after the listener started to receive location updates. What is the proper way to do that?

Comment: stop location updates, change the interval then start it again

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    //remove location updates so that it resets
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);

    //change the time of location updates
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(TIME_INTERVAL)
            .setFastestInterval(TIME_INTERVAL_MIN);

    //restart location updates with the new interval
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
```

Comment: I am having problems with this, it seems that whenever I remove the location updates the location tracking just stops working altogether

Comment: @hoffmann make sure you initialize the location request again and the fused location api. it should work. simple stop/start